# How do I get the current time of an iTunes track via Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, itunes

I am currently using some generated headers for iTunes from some scripting interface thing (ScriptingBridge?). I can get the name of the song currently being played with

```
[[iTunes currentTrack] name];
```

but I can't seem to be able to get the current time of the song playback. I am not using Applescript at the moment.

Edit: Definitely generated via ScriptingBridge. I generated the header with

```
sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename iTunes
```

Comment: This question needs a bit more info, please.

Comment: Your request for more info needs more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it:
    [iTunes playerPosition]

Comment: This is because `player position` is a property of the application, not of a track. You'll see the same if you view iTunes's dictionary in AppleScript Editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is AppleScript; I know you aren't using it but I don't know how to do this with Scripting Bridge. From what I know, the method should be similar but closer to objective-c syntax.

```
tell application "iTunes"
set this_time to time of current track as string
set elapsed_seconds to player position
set this_elapsed_minutes to round elapsed_seconds / 60 rounding down
set this_elapsed_seconds to elapsed_seconds mod 60
if {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} contains this_elapsed_seconds then
set this_elapsed_seconds to "0" & (this_elapsed_seconds as string)
end if
end tell    

return (this_elapsed_minutes & ":" & this_elapsed_seconds & " of " & this_time) as text --
```